# REGEXP Error - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently learning SQL and using SSMS 2017. I can't understand why I am getting an error when using the REGEXP syntax that it seems to work for anyone else:

```
SELECT *
FROM List
WHERE Name REGEXP '^.[a-e].*'
ORDER BY Name;
```

> Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where
>   a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'.

Comment: Presumably you are learning SQL Server using SMSS, and SQL Server does not have built-in support for regular expressions.

Comment: SSMS can only work with SQL Server - not with MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is a SQL Server error, not a MySQL error.  SMSS is a Microsoft product, usually used with SQL Server.  Hence, I conclude that you are learning SQL Server.

SQL Server does not support the `REGEXP` operator.  But it does extend the `LIKE` pattern matching.  You can do what you want as:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM List l
WHERE l.Name LIKE '%[a-e]%'
ORDER BY Name;
```

It is also worth noting that your `REGEXP` pattern is more complicated than necessary.  Regular expressions match anywhere in the string, so this finds any names that have the letters "a" through "e":

```
    WHERE Name REGEXP '[a-e]'
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer.